# Manually route to application instances

Tags: cloud-foundry

As an OpenPaaS, Cloud Foundry supports to scale up and down application instances just with simple VMC command: `vmc instances <appname> <num|delta>`, as I know.

Even Cloud Foundry supports dynamically route the "user" requests to the instances. It's very good!

And here, what I want to know is if Cloud Foundry supports that I manually (maybe some commands or other technicalities) route for using the instance? For example, when I scale up two instances and one of them is very busy to response "user" requests, so in this case, I want to route the "user" requests to the "lazy" instance manually!

Answer (score 1):

In Cloud Foundry when you add instances to your app, it actually does sticky session. There isn't a way for users to direct traffic to a specific instance.

Comment: Sorry, Ali Moghadam, I have some questions ! (1)As you said, the "user" is indicating "end-user" or "developer" ? (2)Another one is, as a "developer" if I can edit "Router" information? If I can, which file I can edit ? Best regards !

Comment: By user I mean the developer. There is no way the developer can modify the router information. The only way you would be able to do that is having your own instance of VCAP running and modifying the router yourself (via ssh into your VCAP instance). And also modifying the router is not a great thing because then you are modifying the default behavior which is sticky session. 

If you are using cloudfoundry.com, there is no way.

Comment: Thanks Ali Moghadam ! I have already setup VCAP on my PC, so if there are some documents how to modify "router"? I just want to route the request to which "I need to request" instance(application instance) ! Waiting your answer, best regards !

Comment: The best place to ask this question would be in https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/vcap-dev

Comment: Sorry, Ali Moghadam! There is no response about "Manually Route to the Application Instance" problem, in the Google group ! So, how can I manually route to the application instance? Are there any API which I can use or modify for my goal? Best regards !