# How actuator endpoint will work in clustered env

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

If I add spring starter for actuator and if my application is deployed in Cloud foundry , lets say I have 4 instances...one endpoint will give me overall health from all 4 instaces ??

Answer (score 0):

No.

The actuator "extends" the REST interface of your application. Each application runs isolated and does not know anything about other instances in Cloud Foundry. A request to the application (i.e. to an actuator endpoint) is load balanced by Cloud Foundry to one of the running instances of your application. This means that you will only see the health /state of this one particular instance.

Given the information in this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686567/manually-route-to-application-instances) there is now way of "manually" accessing a certain instance of your app. This means that you can't even "collect" all health states of your application instances "manually" using actuator.

Comment: Thanks Mike, was expecting that cloud foundry with spring boot magic will serve the purpose....